# how to use pagination query in fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, pagination

I want to use following query in fluent nHibernate:

```
_dataContext.Products
    .Where(filterExpression)
    .OrderBy(sortExpression + " " + sortDirection)
    .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize);
```

Comment: Where is the question here? You will have to expand to get answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in both Criteria and HQL use

```
.SetFirstResult(pageIndex * pageSize).SetMaxResults(pageSize)
```

LinqToNhibernate:

```
session.Query<Product>()
  .Where(filterExpression)
  .OrderBy(sortExpression + " " + sortDirection)
  .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
  .Take(pageSize);
```